# How can I compare a textfield.settext?

Tags: java, textfield, settext

How can i campare a textfield.settext with a string for example:

```
if(textField_1.setText != ("Hello"))
```

I can't do !=, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the string comparision should be done.

```
if(textField_1.setText.equals("Hello")){

}
```

**Update:**
I think you must use the get method to get the text, therefore I am expecting `textField_1.getText()` will give you the text to be compared.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

Comment: I wrote that and it shows this error: setText cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score 1):

`if(!textField_1.setText.equals("Hello"))`

That's Java :)

you can use != and == to compare references and basic types (int, float ... )

In c++ we can overload the operator, but in java we have to use `equals()`

Comment: I wrote that and it shows this error:

    setText cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Don't you want to use method `getText()`?  if textField_1 is Swing object then `setText()` and `getText()` are methods

Comment: at the begging of my code i put the "Hello" value ( textField_1.setText("Nº OPERARIO"); ), and after that i wan't to compare it and i used if(textField_1.setText.equals("Nº OPERARIO")) but ir shows that error

Comment: use textField_1.getText().equals("asasasas")

Comment: and how is, is not equal?

Comment: Add '!' before all, its in my answear

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getText()` method to compare.

```
if(textField_1.getText() != ("Hello")){
//not matched
}else{
//matched
}
```

But it is better to use equals() method to compare.

```
if(!textField_1.getText().equals("Hello")){
//not matched
}else{
//matched
}
```

Note That:
`==` tests for reference equality.

`.equals(`) tests for value equality.